# Отправить письмо с сайт без редикта (код внутри)

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

при нажатии кнопки выполняется код php , но на новой странице , как сделать что бы при нажатии просто появилось модальное окно что операция успешно выполнена (в моем случае письмо доставлено или нет )

```
<?php

$telefon = htmlspecialchars($_POST["telefon"]);

$address = "email на который приходит письмо";
$sub = "сообщение с сайта";
$email = "none";
$mes = "сообщение с сатйа \n
телефон :$telefon";

$from = "From: $sub <$email> \r\n Reply-To: $email \r\n";
if (mail($address, $sub, $mes)) 
{
    header('Refresh:5; URL = редикт на сайт при успехе');
    echo '<head>
    <meta http-equiv = "Content-Type" content = "text/html; charset=utf-8" /></head>
    <body>Письмо отправлено, через 5 секунд вы вернетесь обратно на страницу</body>';}
    else {
        header('Refresh: 5; URL = редикт при неудаче');
        echo '<head>
        <meta http-equiv = "Content-Type" content = "text/html; charset=utf-8" /></head>
        <body>Письмо не отправлено, через 5 секунд вы вернетесь обратно на страницу</body>';}
        exit;
        ?>
```

Comment: Как вариант можно попробовать с использованием alert на javascript

Comment: Если вы хотите что бы, все происходило без перезагрузки страницы используйте ajax на языке javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант: на странице, где форма, создайте окошко с id="result", куда будет выводиться ответ от сервера, и скройте его. Там же разместите примерно такой jquery-код:

```
$('button[name=submit]').click(function(e) { //кликаем кнопку "отправить"
  e.preventDefault(); //предотвращаем переход на страницу с php-сценарием
    var form = $('#formID'); //передаём в переменную нашу форму
    $.ajax({ //отправляем ajax-запрос
      cashe: false, //предотвращаем его кеширование
      type: form.attr('method'), //определяем метод передачи...
      url: form.attr('action'), //...и файл-обработчик
      data: form.serialize(), //сериализуем данные формы
      success: function(data) { //получаем ответ от сервера
        $('#result').html(data); //выводим ответ в наше скрытое окошко
        $('#result').slideDown(); //открываем это окошко для показа пользователю
        setTimeout(function(){$('#result').slideUp()}, 5000); //через 5 секунд скрываем окошко
      }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: В ответ приходит весь сайт а не результат операции , какое то наложение происходит двух одинаковых страниц и потом через 5 сек страница исчезает

Comment: ну, потому что надо ответ изменить: там должна быть только строка сообщения и больше никакой информации - никаких хедеров, тегов и т.д. Просто echo 'Письмо отправлено' или echo 'Письмо не отправлено'

Comment: Большое спасибо , все работает ) я как то сам не догадался изменить исходный файл )

Comment: есть ответ помог, примите его, поставив рядом галочку )